# My ~ and ± keys are switched, how can I switch back?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

As the title says the keys described above have been switched, how can I switch them on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this program. It should sort your problem out in no time. http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/

However this one works as well: 
http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele

Take your pick!

Comment: I wasn't really looking for a addtiona software solution, but it answers the question. I was hoping there would be a way using just OS X

Comment: Using the second link you can create an XMl to put in the /Library/Kayboard\ Layouts folder, which isn't really using other program's too much.